# Angular UI Bootstrap Calendar Year Selector

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-bootstrap

Is there a way to configure the popup calendar widget such that the user can select the year from a dropdownlist? Kinda like this:

[image]

It is not a requirement I am fond of, but a requirement I am stuck with. Seems like jQueryUi's picker is about the only modern one that does that.

Thanks

Comment: what is the question here ? you are using ui bootstrap calendar or Jquery ? If it's bootstrap then you want it look like the above calendar ?

Comment: ui-bootstrap is customizable, you can define your own templates

Comment: @Angular_10 I don't want the whole widget to look like that example. All I want in the dropdownlist for the Year selection. Out of the box, ui bootstrap does not have this and there is no configuration option specifically which provides this. Not using jQuery. Just made the comment that the jQueryUI widget does support that dropdownlist for the year selector.

Comment: @svarog Thanks. I will look into templates.